# How to prevent users from creating an account if username is already taken

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have no idea how to block users from creating account if the username is already taken.. Can someone help me.. I try looking scripts or tutorial on the internet but they're no good.. I'm just a noobie in coding.. my table is called "user_acc" and the username field is "username"

here's my ajax script

```
function validateEmail(str){ 
    var testresults;

    var filter=/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    //var filter1=/^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if (filter.test(str))
        testresults=true;
    else
        testresults=false

    return (testresults)
    }



//registration
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submbut').click(function(){

    var fn = $('#fnamae').val();    
    var ln = $('#lnamae').val();
    var un = $('#unamae').val();
    var pass = $('#pass').val();
    var pass2 = $('#pass2').val();
    var mail = $('#mail').val();
    var cont = $('#cont').val();

    var url = "http://localhost/picturecity/acceptusr";

if(fn == "" && ln == "" && un == "" && pass == "" && pass2 == "" && mail == "" && cont == "" || fn == "" || ln == "" || un == "" || pass == "" 
    || pass2 == "" || mail == "" || cont == ""){
 alert('Error: Fill up all fields');
}
else{
     if(pass == pass2)
     {
            if(validateEmail(mail)){
                $.ajax({
                    url:url,
                    data: "fn="+fn+"&ln="+ln+"&un="+un+"&pass="+pass+"&mail="+mail+"&cont="+cont,
                    type:"post",
                    success:function(e){

                        alert('Registration Successful');
                    }//success


                    });//ajax
             }

             else{
                alert("Invalid Email Format");
             }
    }//if

    else{
        alert('Password Do Not Match');
    }
}   







    });//click

}); //document
```

my controller code for registration

```
public function acceptusr(){
    $data = array (
            "firstname"=>$this->input->post('fn'),
            "lastname"=>$this->input->post('ln'),
            "username"=>$this->input->post('un'),
            "password"=>md5($this->input->post('pass')),
            "email"=>$this->input->post('mail'),
            "contact"=>$this->input->post('cont')

        );

    $this->Mod_admin->addtotb('user_acc',$data); 
}
```

the model

```
public function addtotb($table, $data)
{
    $this->db->insert($table,$data);
}
```

please help me how to create username validation thanks..

Comment: You should check whether user with this nickname already exists in database (using `SELECT`) or not.

Comment: You will have to do a database request to check if the username is taken. You can do this either using ajax in your jquery code or by adding a test in your acceptusr() function.

Comment: I believe codeigniter can handle database-exceptions... so simply set your database table-column to `UNIQUE` and handle the exception?

Comment: *"I try looking scripts or tutorial on the internet but they're no good.. I'm just a noobie in coding"* - That's what those tutorials are for.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do a simple validation. If you are using AJAX, you need to perform these steps.

1. Send the `username` to the server.
2. Check for the existence of the `username` in the Database.
3. Respond to the client with `true` or `false` depending on the presence of the `username`.
4. Based on the response, send the user a client side alert!

So to do that, you need to verify it from the server. What you are doing in your question you have posted is just a validation of Email address. Assuming you are familiar with jQuery's AJAX functions, you need to do the following:

1. **Send the `username` to the server.**

   ```
   $.get("checkuser.php", {username: $("#username").val()}, function (response) {
   });
   ```
2. **Check for the existence of the `username` in the Database.**

   ```
   $db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=" . $_GET["username"]);
   ```
3. **Respond to the client with `true` or `false` depending on the presence of the `username`.**

   ```
   if ($db->rowCount() == 1)
     die ("true");
   else
     die ("false");
   ```
4. **Based on the response, send the user a client side alert!**

   ```
   $.get("checkuser.php", {username: $("#username").val()}, function (response) {
     if (response == "true")
     {
       alert("User already exists!");
       return false;
     }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to make the DB table row "username" [unique](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html).

Answer (score 1):

very simple set mysql column where user name stored as unique.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
  ADD UNIQUE (usr_name);
```

insert query as

```
$q= mysqli_query($conn,"insert into users values ('xx', 'xx', 'xx')");
if(!$q){
$error= mysqli_error($q);
//or $error="user name already exits "
header("location:login.php?error=$error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before `$this->db->insert($table,$data);` add:

```
$userq = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user_acc WHERE username LIKE '".$data['username']."'");
if($userq->num_rows() == 0)
```

Comment: should I do something in my ajax or i'll just put this in my addtodb function and everything will do?

Comment: If you put this in addtodb it will prevent from adding the user to database. Also if you put after `$this->db->insert($table,$data);` `else return false;` and in `acceptusr()` change `$this->Mod_admin->addtotb('user_acc',$data); ` to `echo $this->Mod_admin->addtotb('user_acc',$data); `, and change `alert('Registration Successful');` to `if(e == false || e == 'false') alert('User already exists!');` you will have the validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* $username is the desired username from New user that was input field and
you can use mysqli too just by chaging my sql to mysqli   all the best  */

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
if(empty($username) or empty($password1) or empty($password2))
{
    echo '<p>Fields Empty !</p>';
}
elseif(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
    echo "User exist";
}
elseif($password1 == $password2)
{
    $password = md5($password1);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES('$username', '$password')");
    echo "<p>Successfull Register</p>";
}
else
{
    echo 'Password Not Matched';
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer

Comment: Brother I am trying to but its giving me errors... that my code is incorrect and not submitting...

Comment: Brother!!! I copy pasted it from one of my project... M sure you are out of problem now. Always check spell, a single mistake is more than sufficient to make error.