# Server-Side PreValidation of User Form and Conditionals (Design/Best Practice)

Tags: python, validation, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Issue: Create a method that verifies if `username` exists when **Creating an Account**, deny account if `username` exists, and advises the user to create a new `username` and  repeat the process should need be.

I have some idea of how to do this based on some STACKS questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085667/creating-lock-so-two-users-dont-create-account-with-the-same-username), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234809/how-to-prevent-users-from-creating-an-account-if-username-is-already-taken)) that I have read on here. Such as something like:

> 1. Send the username to the server.
> 2. Check for the existence of the
>      username in the Database.
> 3. Respond to the client with true or false
>      depending on the presence of the username.
> 4. Based on the response, send
>      the user a client side alert!

I am uncertain how to properly execute the process in the Sign Up Page (also known as the `Create an Account` page) using **Pyramid** and **SQLAlchemy**. Since I am newbie, I want to make sure I am creating code that is fast, efficient and with smart design. I want to ensure I am staying within best practices.

Right now in the `User` database, `Username` is `UNIQUE`; this causes the system to crash when a user tries to create a `username` that exists in the db. My code is missing something as there is a traceback that indicates `DETAIL:  Key (username)=(baseball) already exists.` Any help or suggestions is truly appreciated! If I have a poor method, suggestions of a better method is highly welcomed!

*Software: Python 2.7, Pyramid 1.5.7, SQLAlchemy 1.0.9*

---

**views.py** 
 
(code: to the create a user page and save new user)

```
@view_config(route_name='create_user', request_method='GET', renderer='templates/create_account.jinja2')
def user_form_view(request):
    return {}

@view_config(route_name='save_new_user')
def save_new_user(request):
    with transaction.manager:

        username = request.params['username']

        check_username = api.retrieve_user(username) #retrieves one_user
        #check_users = api.retrieve_users() #this retrieves ALL the users

        taken = False
        for user in check_username: #prints out all user info
            if username == user.username:
                taken = True
                break
        if taken:
            username = request.params['username']

        password = request.params['password']
        firstname = request.params['firstname']
        lastname = request.params['lastname']
        email = request.params['email']

        new_user = api.create_user(username, password, firstname, lastname, email)
        new_account = api.update_group_add_user('Registered User', new_user)

        transaction.commit()
        return HTTPSeeOther(location=request.route_url('login'))
```

Traceback:

```
IntegrityError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely) (psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=(baseball) already exists.
 [SQL: 'INSERT INTO users (username, firstname, lastname, email, password, institution, created_on) VALUES (%(username)s, %(firstname)s, %(lastname)s, %(email)s, %(password)s, %(institution)s, %(created_on)s) RETURNING users.id'] [parameters: {'username': u'baseball', 'firstname': u'jlo', 'lastname': u'lo', 'institution': None, 'created_on': datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 24, 22, 27, 20, 286260), 'password': '78d8045d684abd2eece923758f3cd781489df3a48e1278982466017f', 'email': u'j'}]
```

---

## Updates based on suggestion below

## Question:

Where should I create the function validate_registration -- outside of the registration_view function? Should this be a `Boolean` statement? Is this the best method? Where would `transaction.commit()` exist?

View Code with GET and POST:

```
def validate_registration_form(request):
    with transaction.manager:
        username = request.params['username']
        check_username = api.retrieve_user(username)

        password = request.params['password']
        firstname = request.params['firstname']
        lastname = request.params['lastname']
        email = request.params['email']

        if check_username is not None:
            return False
        else:
            return True

@view_config(route_name='registration', renderer='templates/create_account.jinja2')
@view_config(route_name='save_registration',  renderer='templates/create_account.jinja2')
def registration_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return {} # render the empty form
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if validate_registration_form(request): #save new_user and redirect
            new_user = api.create_user(username, password, firstname, lastname, email)
            new_account = api.update_group_add_user('Registered User', new_user)
            transaction.commit()
            raise HTTPSeeOther(location=request.route_url('login'))
        else:
            # form is not valid, re-render the form
            # with the data user entered and an error message
            return {
                'error_message': 'username already taken',
                'username': request.POST.get('username', ''),
                'password': request.POST.get('password', ''),
                'firstname': request.POST.get('firstname', ''),
                'lastname': request.POST.get('lastname', ''),
                'email': request.POST.get('email', '')
                }
```

form:

```
    <form action="/save_registration" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <dl>
                <dt><label for = 'username'> Username: <em>single word--no spaces</em> </label></dt>
      #more ....
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `api.retrieve_user` does, but it seems like it would only retrieve one user object. Why wrap that in a list only to iterate over one element? Also if the username is taken, you don't take any real action. You'll have to prompt the user to pick a different name, instead.

Comment: @AdamSmith yes, api.retrieve_user only retrieves one user. I'm very new to this... and trying to figure out how to properly do it. I'll add what it does above. I definitely need to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the classic approach to server-side form validation on submit is something like this (in pseudocode):

```
@view_config(route_name='registration', renderer='my_rego_form.jinja2')  # handles both GET and POST
def rego_form(request):
    if request.metod == 'GET':
        return {}  # render the empty form
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if validate_rego_form(request):  
            # create a new user and redirect elsewhere
            create_user(request)
            raise HTTPFound('/post_registration_page') 
        else: 
            # form is not valid, re-render the form 
            # with the data user entered and an error message
            return {
                'error_message': 'Error creating user',
                'username': request.POST.get('username', '')
                'email': request.POST.get('email', '')
                'phone_num': request.POST.get('phone_num', '')
            }
        else:
            # some other HTTP method, not sure how to deal
```

So, basically, the form needs to be able to re-render itself with the data submitted by the client.

The validation method itself can be trivial and just check for the user with the given email in the db. Or, as you tried to do, instead of pre-validation you can try to just create a record and handle the exception if one occurs.

Comment: I added updated code along with the form itself and some questions. The function you call, `validate_rego_form` where does that exist? Outside this scope? It's only supposed to check if those `params` exist in the system correct??? If not, then it should carry that information over and `transaction.commit()` to save to the `db`

Comment: I added the `validation function` code above...which is working.

Comment: @thesayhey: yes, something like this. Does it work now?

Comment: yes it works now! Just wanted to make sure I did it correctly and with best practice in mind. Thank you.